# Merge two vectors based on index in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge two vectors of same length where NAs in vector "a" align with the numbers in vector "b" and vice versa:

```
a <- c(1, NA, 3, NA)
b <- c(NA, 2, NA, 4)
```

The output should be:

```
1, 2 ,3, 4
```

Thanks for the help!

edit: the solution I used was

```
a[is.na(a)] <- b[is.na(a)]
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and explain what didn't work?

Comment: `which` is really not necessary in the edit you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of `a` that correspond to `is.na(a)` should be replaced with the values of `b` that correspond to the negation of `is.na(b)`.  Here I define a new vector `d` so as to not over-write the original vectors `a` or `b`.

```
d <- a
d[is.na(d)] <- b[!is.na(b)]
d
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

If you know the `NA` values begin in the second position, you could also alternate the assignment.

```
d <- a
d[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- b[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
d
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Was just about to post this exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more solutions that might have more "literal" resonance. They have equivalent outputs:

```
m <- mapply(c, na.omit(a), na.omit(b), SIMPLIFY= FALSE)  ## or,
m <- Map(c, na.omit(a), na.omit(b))

output <- unlist(m)  ## or,
output <- Reduce(c, m)
```

What this does it first concatenates pairs across `na.omit(a)` and `na.omit(b)`, and then concatenates all those pairs together.

As far as performance goes, here is a quick benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)

gc()

a <- (1:1e4)[c(TRUE, NA)]
b <- (1:1e4)[c(NA, TRUE)]

microbenchmark(
  unlist(mapply(c, na.omit(a), na.omit(b), SIMPLIFY= FALSE)),
  unlist(Map(c, na.omit(a), na.omit(b))),
  Reduce(c, mapply(c, na.omit(a), na.omit(b), SIMPLIFY= FALSE)),
  Reduce(c, Map(c, na.omit(a), na.omit(b))),
  times = 100
)

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq
# unlist(mapply(c, na.omit(a), na.omit(b), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))  4.476689  5.103025
# unlist(Map(c, na.omit(a), na.omit(b)))  4.475753  4.902474
# Reduce(c, mapply(c, na.omit(a), na.omit(b), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)) 75.974627 82.953051
# Reduce(c, Map(c, na.omit(a), na.omit(b))) 75.919419 82.626217
# median        uq       max neval
# 5.488113  5.723023  10.59291   100
# 5.422528  5.784764  13.04502   100
# 86.082578 89.652660 114.94584   100
# 85.761412 89.550317 158.90629   100
```

Unsurprisingly, `Reduce` is much slower than `unlist`. `Map` is only slightly slower than `mapply`. However `Reduce` is much, much more generally applicable, whereas `unlist` can really only handle this special case.

Comment: This solution works only if the number of NAs are the same in each vector.

Comment: Very true, but I wasn't sure if this was more of a "collating" problem or a "filling in NA's" problem. This is definitely geared towards the former and not the latter.

Comment: Very much a "filling in NAs" problem. Actually the solution I was hoping for is to specify the indices of NAs from vector a and insert the values of b.

Comment: @user2535289 - the indices can be obtained with `which(is.na(a))` and `which(is.na(b))`